# How to draw a rectangle with one different border

Tags: wpf, xaml, drawing, shapes

i want a rectangle with this measures left=50, top=20, rigth=50 and **bottom=10** in XAML

Something like

thanks[image: Something like]

**UPDATE:**

i want to create a Grid with that shape, i said grid because the control should contain other controls like an image and this control should grow or shrink with the form.

Comment: Umm... that's not a rectangle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Shape you are showing is not a rectangle.

You'll need a Path to do this:

```
<Path Data="M0,0 L20,0 L10,50 L0,50 z"
      Fill="White" 
      Height="50" 
      Stroke="Black"
      Width="20"/>
```

Comment: @Erno its posible to create a grid with that shape??

Comment: @Christian, can you give an example (drawing & description of how it should work)?

Comment: @Christian, your description of the grid is lacks detail. How do you want the nested controls to repond to the shape of the grid; how should the rows and columns respond to the shape?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a Border:

```
<Border BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="50 20 50 10"/>
```

Comment: This will adjust the border thickness not the shape.